# Letters on PCB silkscreen

Tags: pcb

I noticed that on many PCBs, on the silkscreen, boxed letters (A B C E E ...) are often added.

[image]

What exactly are they for?

Does this element have a name with which I can look for more info?

Comment: Looks like layer numbering given that bottom two is mirrored, but I've never seen letters used instead of numbers.

Comment: It might be used to indicate a modification status.

Answer (score 3):

Its most likely a rev marker, so you can identify the rev of the gerbers easily. The letters are are different revs, this deisgn is on rev H. If you reved the design it would be on rev I for the next iteration.

As far as element, it would likely depend on the software.

Comment: Maybe revision "I" for the next revision?

Comment: Yeah, just my lysdexia